# highscore in pygame game

Tags: python, pygame

I've made a game in pygame and I want to make it possible to have a high score thaat will be displayed at the the top of the show_go_screen. I just need a simple solution - I don't need to write who has the highest score, just the number itself at the top of the show_go_screen. I know there are already questions about this on Stack Overflow but the solutions don't work for me.

code:

```
# Pygame template

# Attributions

# (Heart) Icons made by <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/freepik" title="Freepik">Freepik</a> from <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon"> www.flaticon.com</a>
# (Play)<a href="https://www.freepik.com/free-photos-vectors/Background">Background vector created by freepik - www.freepik.com</a>
# (GameOver)<a href="https://www.freepik.com/free-photos-vectors/background">Background vector created by pikisuperstar - www.freepik.com</a>
# (Backing)Frozen Jam by tgfcoder <https://twitter.com/tgfcoder> licensed under CC-BY-3 <http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/>
# (Graphics)Art by Kenney.nl

# Imports
import pygame as pg
import random
from os import path

# images / sound
img_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'img')
snd_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'snd')

# Constants
WIDTH = 500
HEIGHT = 700
FPS = 60
POWERUP_TIME = 60000
ENCO_TIME = 40000

# Define Colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
MAGENTA = (255, 0, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
CYAN = (0, 255, 255)
GREENISH_BLUE = (0, 255, 180)

# Initialize pygame and create window
pg.init()
pg.mixer.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pg.display.set_caption("Galaxy Shooters")
clock = pg.time.Clock()

score = 0
# save score
# import shelve
# d = shelve.open('score.txt')  # here you will save the score variable
# d['highscore'] = score            # thats all, now it is saved on disk.
# d.close()

font_name = pg.font.match_font('arial')
def draw_text(surf, text, size, x, y):
    font = pg.font.Font(font_name, size)
    text_surface = font.render(text, True, CYAN)
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
    text_rect.midtop = (x, y)
    surf.blit(text_surface, text_rect)

def spawnmob():
    m = Mob()
    all_sprites.add(m)
    mobs.add(m)

def draw_shield_status_bar(surf, x, y, pct):
    if pct < 0:
        pct = 0
    BAR_LENGTH = 100
    BAR_HEIGHT = 10
    fill = (pct / 100) * BAR_LENGTH
    outline_rect = pg.Rect(x, y, BAR_LENGTH, BAR_HEIGHT)
    fill_rect = pg.Rect(x, y, fill, BAR_HEIGHT)
    pg.draw.rect(surf, GREENISH_BLUE, fill_rect)
    pg.draw.rect(surf, WHITE, outline_rect, 2)

def draw_lives(surf, x, y, lives, img):
    for i in range(lives):
        img_rect = img.get_rect()
        img_rect.x = x + 30 * i
        img_rect.y = y
        surf.blit(img, img_rect)

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.transform.scale(player_img, (50, 38))
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.radius = 20
        # pg.draw.circle(self.image, RED, self.rect.center, self.radius)
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 10
        self.speedx = 0
        self.shield = 100
        self.shoot_delay = 370
        self.last_shot = pg.time.get_ticks()
        self.lives = 3
        self.hidden = False
        self.hide_timer = pg.time.get_ticks()
        self.power = 1
        self.power_time = pg.time.get_ticks()

    def update(self):
        # Timeout for powerups
        if self.power >= 2 and pg.time.get_ticks() - self.hide_timer > POWERUP_TIME:
            self.power -= 1
            self.power_time = pg.time.get_ticks

        # Unhide if necessary
        if self.hidden and pg.time.get_ticks() - self.hide_timer > 1000:
            self.hidden = False
            self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
            self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 10
        self.speedx = 0
        keystate = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pg.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -5
        if keystate[pg.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 5
        if keystate[pg.K_SPACE]:
            self.shoot()
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

    def powerup(self):
        self.power += 1
        self.power_time = pg.time.get_ticks()

    def shoot(self):
        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_shot > self.shoot_delay:
            self.last_shot = now
            if self.power == 1:
                laser = Laser(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top)
                all_sprites.add(laser)
                lasers.add(laser)
                random.choice(shoot_sounds).play()
            if self.power >= 2:
                laser1 = Laser(self.rect.left, self.rect.centery)
                laser2 = Laser(self.rect.right, self.rect.centery)
                all_sprites.add(laser1)
                all_sprites.add(laser2)
                lasers.add(laser1)
                lasers.add(laser2)
                random.choice(shoot_sounds).play()

    def hide(self):
        self.hidden = True
        self.hide_timer = pg.time.get_ticks()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT + 200)

class Mob(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image_orig = random.choice(meteor_images)
        self.image_orig.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.image = self.image_orig.copy()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.radius = int(self.rect.width * .85 / 2)
        # pg.draw.circle(self.image, RED, self.rect.center, self.radius)
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-150, -40)
        self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 8)
        self.speedx = random.randrange(-3, 3)
        self.rot = 0
        self.rot_speed = random.randrange(-8, 8)
        self.last_update = pg.time.get_ticks()

    def rotate(self):
        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_update > 50:
            self.last_update = now
            self.rot = (self.rot + self.rot_speed) % 360
            new_image = pg.transform.rotate(self.image_orig, self.rot)
            old_center = self.rect.center
            self.image = new_image
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = old_center

    def update(self):
        self.rotate()
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.top > HEIGHT + 10 or self.rect.right < -25 or self.rect.left > WIDTH + 20:
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.width)
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
            self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 8)

class Laser(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = laser_img
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.speedy = -10

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        # Kill it if moves off the top of the screen
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.kill()

class Explosion(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, center, size):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.size = size
        self.image = explosion_anim[self.size][0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = center
        self.frame = 0
        self.last_update = pg.time.get_ticks()
        self.frame_rate = 75

    def update(self):
        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_update > self.frame_rate:
            self.last_update = now
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame == len(explosion_anim[self.size]):
                self.kill()
            else:
                center = self.rect.center
                self.image = explosion_anim[self.size][self.frame]
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                self.rect.center = center

class Pow(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, center):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.type = random.choice(['shield', 'laser', 'star'])
        self.image = powerup_images[self.type]
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = center
        self.speedy = 4

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        # Kill it if moves off the bottom of the screen
        if self.rect.top > HEIGHT:
            self.kill()

class Enco(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = draw_text(screen, (random.choice(encos), 37, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT/ 4))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.hidden = True
        self.hide_timer = pg.time.get_ticks()

    def hide(self):
        self.rect.y = HEIGHT - 40
        self.rect.x = WIDTH / 2



def show_go_screen():
    screen.blit(background2, background_rect2)
    draw_text(screen, str(score), 25, WIDTH / 2, 10)
    draw_text(screen, " Guardians of the Galaxy ", 37, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 4)
    draw_text(screen, "Arrow Keys move, Spacebar to shoot", 29, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
    draw_text(screen, "Press any key to BEGIN", 22, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT *  3/ 4)
    pg.display.flip()
    print(d)
    waiting = True
    while waiting:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit()
            if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
                waiting = False

# Load all game graphics
background = pg.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "2397814.jpg")).convert()
background_rect = background.get_rect()
background2 = pg.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "2474216.jpg")).convert()
background_rect2 = background2.get_rect()
pg.transform.scale(background, (500, 700))
player_img = pg.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "playerShip3_blue.png")).convert()
heart_img = pg.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "heart.png")).convert()
mini_heart_img = pg.transform.scale(heart_img, (23, 23))
mini_heart_img.set_colorkey(BLACK)
laser_img = pg.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "laserBlue01.png")).convert()
meteor_images = []
meteor_list = ['meteorBrown_big1.png', 'meteorBrown_big2.png', 'meteorBrown_big3.png',
                'meteorBrown_med1.png','meteorBrown_small1.png','meteorBrown_small2.png',
                'meteorBrown_tiny2.png',]
for img in meteor_list:
    meteor_images.append(pg.image.load(path.join(img_dir, img)).convert())
explosion_anim = {}
explosion_anim['lg'] = []
explosion_anim['sm'] = []
explosion_anim['player'] = []
for i in range(9):
    filename = 'regularExplosion0{}.png'.format(i)
    img = pg.image.load(path.join(img_dir, filename)).convert()
    img.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    img_lg = pg.transform.scale(img, (75, 75))
    explosion_anim['lg'].append(img_lg)
    img_sm = pg.transform.scale(img, (32, 32))
    explosion_anim['sm'].append(img_sm)
    filename = 'sonicExplosion0{}.png'.format(i)
    img = pg.image.load(path.join(img_dir, filename)).convert()
    img.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    explosion_anim['player'].append(img)
powerup_images = {}
powerup_images['shield'] = pg.image.load(path.join(img_dir, 'shield_silver.png')).convert()
powerup_images['laser'] = pg.image.load(path.join(img_dir, 'bolt_gold.png')).convert()
powerup_images['star'] = pg.image.load(path.join(img_dir, 'star_silver.png')).convert()
encos = ("Nice Job!", "You're rocking it man!", " Great!", "What a blast!", "Good one!", "Those asteroids stand no chance against you!"
        "You're the master!")
# Load all game sounds
laser_powerup = pg.mixer.Sound(path.join(snd_dir, 'Laser_Powerup.wav'))
shield_powerup = pg.mixer.Sound(path.join(snd_dir, 'Shield_Powerup.wav'))
shoot_sounds = []
for snd in ['Laser_Shoot.wav', 'Laser_Shoot2.wav']:
    shoot_sounds.append(pg.mixer.Sound(path.join(snd_dir, snd)))
expl_sounds = []
for snd in ['Expl.wav', 'Expl2.wav']:
    expl_sounds.append(pg.mixer.Sound(path.join(snd_dir, snd)))
player_die_sound = pg.mixer.Sound(path.join(snd_dir, 'rumble1.ogg'))
pg.mixer.music.load(path.join(snd_dir, 'tgfcoder-FrozenJam-SeamlessLoop.ogg'))
pg.mixer.music.set_volume(0.7)

pg.mixer.music.play(loops = -1)
# Game loop
game_over = True
running = True
while running:
    if game_over:
        show_go_screen()
        game_over = False
        # Sprite groups
        all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        mobs = pg.sprite.Group()
        lasers = pg.sprite.Group()
        powerups = pg.sprite.Group()
        player = Player()
        all_sprites.add(player)
        for i in range(8):
            spawnmob()

        score = 0
    # Keep loop running at the right speed
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # Events
    for event in pg.event.get():
        # Check for closing window
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False

    # Update
    all_sprites.update()

    # Check to see if a laser hit a mob
    hits = pg.sprite.groupcollide(mobs, lasers, True, True)
    for hit in hits:
        score += 50 - hit.radius
        random.choice(expl_sounds).play()
        expl = Explosion(hit.rect.center, 'lg')
        all_sprites.add(expl)
        if random.random() > 0.93:
            pow = Pow(hit.rect.center)
            all_sprites.add(pow)
            powerups.add(pow)
        spawnmob()

    # Check to see if a mob hit the player
    hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(player, mobs, True, pg.sprite.collide_circle)
    for hit in hits:
        player.shield -= hit.radius * 2
        expl = Explosion(hit.rect.center, 'sm')
        all_sprites.add(expl)
        spawnmob()
        if player.shield <= 0:
            player_die_sound.play()
            death_expl = Explosion(player.rect.center, 'player')
            all_sprites.add(death_expl)
            player.hide()
            player.lives -= 1
            player.shield = 100

    # Check to see if player hit a powerup
    hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(player, powerups, True)
    for hit in hits:
        if hit.type == 'shield':
            pow.kill()
            player.shield += random.randrange(10, 30)
            shield_powerup.play()
            if player.shield >= 100:
                player.shield = 100
        if hit.type == 'laser':
            player.powerup()
            laser_powerup.play()
        if hit.type == 'star':
            player.lives += 1
            if player.lives >= 3:
                player.lives = 3

    # If the player died and the explosion finished playing
    if player.lives == 0 and not death_expl.alive():
        game_over = True
    # Render
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    screen.blit(background, background_rect)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    draw_text(screen, str(score), 25, WIDTH / 2, 10)
    draw_shield_status_bar(screen, 5, 5, player.shield)
    draw_lives(screen, WIDTH - 100, 5, player.lives, mini_heart_img)
    if score == 500:
        draw_text(screen, "Nice Job!", 37, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        last.enco = pg.time.get_ticks()
        if now - last.enco == ENCO_TIME:
            hide_enco

    # *After* drawing everything, flip the display
    pg.display.flip()

pg.quit()
```

thanks!

Comment: Please condense your code down to a [mre]. 
It's a pain to read line after line of irrelevant code, so having a _minimal_ reproducible example helps people spot your problem easier. 
Moreover, the exercise of creating a MRE forces you to look at your code and try to isolate the problem, 
which can often help you figure out the issue without even having to ask on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable called `highscore` then then when the player looses, check if the current score is higher than `highscore` and if it is, then assign the `score` to `highscore`. Then you can just easily add a label with the `highscore` variable as a text

```py
score = 0
highscore = 0
# save score
# import shelve
# d = shelve.open('score.txt')  # here you will save the score variable
# d['highscore'] = score            # thats all, now it is saved on disk.
# d.close()

# A lot of your code

def show_go_screen():
    screen.blit(background2, background_rect2)
    draw_text(screen, str(highscore), 50, WIDTH / 2, 10) #change the x value accordingly

# more of your code

while running:
    if game_over:
        show_go_screen()
        game_over = False
        # Sprite groups
        all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        mobs = pg.sprite.Group()
        lasers = pg.sprite.Group()
        powerups = pg.sprite.Group()
        player = Player()
        all_sprites.add(player)
        for i in range(8):
            spawnmob()

        if score > highscore:
            highscore = score

        score = 0
# the rest of your code
```

Comment: No problem, you got it there, I changed my answer